# Input file upload multiple files not working on Mobile device

Tags: javascript, file-upload

I have a generic file up loader which looks like this:

```
<span class="input-group-btn">
    <span class="btn btn-default btn-fill btn-file">
        Browse<input type="file" id="fileInputs" multiple accept="image/*" onclick="resetprogresss()">
    </span>
</span>
```

I can upload multiple files with my Desktop no problems, but When I try and use the same functionality on a mobile device, I cannot seem to select multiple files.

here is the javascript:

```
var Filenames;

function generateUUID() {
    var d = new Date().getTime();
    var uuid = 'xxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function (c) {
        var r = (d + Math.random() * 16) % 16 | 0;
        d = Math.floor(d / 16);
        return (c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8)).toString(16);
    });
    return uuid;
};

var MainPath = generateUUID();
var Names = [];

function UploadFiles() {
    var SetDir = MainPath;
    var fileInputs = document.getElementById("fileInputs");
    if ('files' in fileInputs) {
        if (fileInputs.files.length == 0) {
            alert("Please select a file");
            return;
        } else {
            var file = fileInputs.files[0];
            var ar = $("#AutoResumeBoxs").is(":checked");
            var chunksize = 20000;
            var name = SetDir;

            /*
            Arguments:
                username            name used to create subfolders on the server.
                files               files object from the file input tag.
                uploadStartFunction function that receives a file object just before uploading.
                progressFunction    function that accepts a percent-complete integer value.
                doneFunction        function called when file is uploaded.
                errorFunction       function called when an error occurs.
                chunkSize           size in bytes of each chunk uploaded.
                autoResume          bool to control auto resuming.
            */
            CFUpload(name, fileInputs.files, uploadStarts, progresss, dones, errors, chunksize, ar);
        }
    }
}

function uploadStarts(thisfile) {
    Names.push(thisfile.name);


}

function progresss(percent) {

    var p = percent + "%";
    $("#lblUPs").text(p);
    $("#progressbars").width(p);
    $("#progressbars").attr("data-appear-progress-animation", p);
    $("#ProgressTabs").text(p);
}

function resetprogresss() {
    progresss(0);
}

function dones() {


}

function errors(data) {

}

function setCookie(c_name, value, exdays) {
    var exdate = new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value = escape(value) + ((exdays == null) ? "" : "; expires=" + exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie = c_name + "=" + c_value;
}

function getCookie(c_name) {
    var c_value = document.cookie;
    var c_start = c_value.indexOf(" " + c_name + "=");
    if (c_start == -1) {
        c_start = c_value.indexOf(c_name + "=");
    }
    if (c_start == -1) {
        c_value = null;
    }
    else {
        c_start = c_value.indexOf("=", c_start) + 1;
        var c_end = c_value.indexOf(";", c_start);
        if (c_end == -1) {
            c_end = c_value.length;
        }
        c_value = unescape(c_value.substring(c_start, c_end));
    }
    return c_value;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#urls").hide();
    document.getElementById("saveme").disabled = true;

    var username = getCookie("username");
});
```

I use this [library](http://carlfranklin.net/blog/2013/6/20/carls-file-uploader-a-nice-little-file-uploader-for-htmljsjq.html) to upload the files. Any Advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: i can select multiple files using ctrl , how are you planning to do this on mobile ?

Comment: @ProllyGeek I am not sure that is what I am trying to find out. I want to select multiple files from mobile, with this, I have already created the Web-API methods, the jQuery upload to the Web-API, but I cannot select multiple files from my mobile phone gallery to utilize for upload.

Comment: @Jacquer Bronkhorst when i tried your code http://fiddle.jshell.net/prollygeek/n3Lvjo81/ , i could only choose files pressing ctrl + multiple files ! is there any other behaviour im not aware of ?

Comment: @ProllyGeek yeah, go to that URL with your **mobile device**. And try and upload multiple files

Comment: but i dont have a ctrl button on my mobile keyboard !

Comment: @ProllyGeek I Know.... That is the question, how can I select multiple files to upload from mobile. Normally when you open the gallery and click and hold on on the image with _Android OS_, you can select multiple files. But this control does not allow that functionality, don't focus on the ctrl button aspect of the question, but the functionality of the control on mobile device

Comment: ohhhhh lol got it , umm let me think of a workaround

Comment: considering the dev is having trouble divining the method to select many, can we expect a plain user to figure it out? sounds like it might be best to corral around having multiple buttons, KISS.

Comment: @dandavis I understand the premise of adding more buttons to enable users to upload more images from certain devices, but I was looking for a simplistic solution to utilize one control to keep the design of the UI uniform. Adding a dynamic method/element to recreate the control to upload multiple images is all well and simplistic enough but it will make my UI clunky. Looking at it, it seems that it's only a problem consisting with the Android OS which is quite sad seeing as here in Africa bulk smart phone devices are android...

Comment: no js solution is going to change how multiple files are actually selected; they all rely on the native <input type=file> behavior. given that, i would try to make the process  as intuitive as possible, even at the cost of a few extra taps for "power users".

Comment: @dandavis can you post your last comment as an answer, I believe it gives the best approach and best explanation for what I am trying to achieve

Answer (score 7):

Well it depends on the selection method you choose on your mobile , however , my native Gallery , and file manager absloutely work fine on my mobile , just tap and hold the file you want to upload , and it will switch to multi selection mode :

[image: Multiple Upload]

[image: Multiple Choice]

Please note that there are many jQuery plugins out there to upload files like **[this one](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/)** , so it is not necessary to use pure html input tag.